# Fluent Wait in Selenium is returning No Such element exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public static void waitUntilPageLoadedAndElementVisible(WebDriver driver, String PageName, By locator) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
         
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(locator);
            }
        }); 
    }
    


public static void waitUntilPageLoadedAndElementVisible(WebDriver driver, String PageName, By locator) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.and(
            webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"),
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator),
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator),
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(locator))
    ));
   

}
```

I have written a Fluent wait with above cases, and in Both cases if i remove Thread.sleep(2000), it is failing and showing No such Element Exception

If I debug, it is working fie. but on run it is not working..

what is the problem in this code..

Comment: Since it might be a language-related issue you'd better add a programing language tag as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct import for NoSuchElementException Exception class

You have to import

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
```

you might have imported below which is incorrect

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
```

Example

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

public class Example {

    public static void waitUntilPageLoadedAndElementVisible(WebDriver driver, String PageName,
    By locator) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    WebElement element = wait.until(d -> d.findElement(locator));
}
}
```

Comment: Amazing guess!  yes. u are right? somehow while doing quick fix. i added this import java.util.NoSuchElementException;.. Thank u.. now it is workng perfectly..